# What is the importance of setting up icons on templates

Tags: templates

I was looking up what the competencies are for Sitecore 9.1 examination and stumbled upon [this blog](https://sitecore.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/16000088542-sitecore-9-1-certified-platform-associate-developer-exam-study-guide) where one of the stated competencies under Templates is as followed:

> State the importance of setting up icons on data templates

[image]

What would this be, other than better usability by easier recognition of template types?

Comment: Anh-Duc, this is really a better question for the community on Sitecore Slack channel. This is an opinion based question. https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/10/27/how-to-join-sitecore-slack-community-chat/

Comment: @ChrisAuer you can now use the new url for the chat: https://sitecore.chat/ :)

Comment: Hey now. Didn't know about that. Thank you.

Comment: @ChrisAuer this makes me wonder why an opinion-based question would even be in the exam, a bit odd ain't it. Would've expected it to be a *fact* based exam, hence my question in the first place.